Python: why list*2 and list+list sometimes (but not always) return the same list?
The code:
k = [[1], [2]]
print(id(k+k), id(k*2))

returns the same number twice, indicating the two expressions direct to the same place in memory.
But the code:
k = [[1], [2]]
print(id(k+k))
print(id(k*2))

returns 2 different numbers, indicating the two expression return two different lists in memory. 
Why does this happen?
I expect either both code snippets to return the same number twice, or both code snippets to return 2 different numbers. Why does the writing in 2 different lines matter to the end result?
Edit: I'm using Python 3.9.2

Note that print(id(k+k), id(k*3)) also give the same address. Ids are guaranteed to be unique at any moment in time, but the object k+k doesn't exist anymore (as there isn't any reference left to it ) when you create k*3, so the same address can be reused. Using Python 3.11, I also get the same behavior for your second example, so I can't reproduce what you say you observe.

"returns the same number twice, indicating the two expressions direct to the same place in memory." since the lifetime of these objects don't overlap, you cannot make that conclusion from the code you have. when k is a list object, the expressions k + k and k * 2 always return new list objects.

id only returns a value that is unique for the lifetime of its argument. Both k + k and k*2 are expressions that produce objects that are only bound to the parameter of id until id returns. So as soon as id(k+k) is evaluated and produces an argument for print, the object created by k+k goes out of scope, and its identifier is available for reuse by k*k. (That is, k+k and k*2 do not exist at the same time.)
Basically, id(a) and id(b) are guaranteed to return different values if a and b exist at the same time. If they don't, nothing is guaranteed: id(a) could equal id(b), but it's not required to.
